# Is there an alternative to \Call{Algorithm}?

Tags: fonts, algorithms

I would like to format names of algorithms just as they appear inside the `algorithmic` environment. For an example, see the title "An unsuccessful attempt: Flip-and-Match" of [this paper](http://www-cgi.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/Web/People/arielpro/papers/weightnmatch.pdf). So far I've been using `\Call{MyFunc}{}`, but guts tell me this is not the right thing to do, and more importantly, it doesn't work if I want to use it in section titles. What is the proper command to use for such cases?

Comment: I couldn't see anything that resembled an algorithm in the work you cite. I think we could help better if you gave us a minimum complete document that illustrates your problem, plus a description or picture shewing what's wrong with it.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for a way to use [small caps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_caps) in the argument of a sectional unit? If this is so, you can use something like `\section{An unsuccessful attempt: {\normalfont\scshape Flip-and-Match}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a macro for your specially formatted names: for example

```
\newcommand{\algoname}[1]{\textnormal{\textsc{#1}}}
```

will produce the result you want when called as

```
\section{An unsuccessful attempt: \algoname{Flip-and-Match}}
Let us warm up by considering the mechanism \algoname{Flip-and-Match} proposed ...
```